# How to convert Jira Curl to Guzzle

Tags: laravel, curl, jira, guzzle

I wrote a code that works great inserting attachments in Jira ticket.

I would like to use Guzzle instead of Curl, but unfortunately I can't do it, can someone help me convert this code?

```
public function addAttachments(UploadedFile $file, String $key)
{
    $cfile = new CURLFile($file, $file->getMimeType(), $file->getClientOriginalName());
     $data = array('file' => $cfile);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://candidwebassets.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/'.$key.'/attachments');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
        'X-Atlassian-Token: no-check',
        'Accept: application/json',
    ]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, env('JIRA_USER').':'.env('JIRA_SECRET'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Please show what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited after discussion below**

Why not use the Laravel `HTTP` class like

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

public function addAttachments(UploadedFile $file, String $key)
{
    $response = Http::withHeaders([
            'X-Atlassian-Token' => 'no-check',
            'Accept' => 'application/json'
        ])
        ->withBasicAuth(env('JIRA_USER'), env('JIRA_SECRET'))
        ->attach('file', file_get_contents($file), $file->getClientOriginalName())
        ->post('https://candidwebassets.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/'.$key.'/attachments');

    if ($response->failed()) {
        throw new Exception($response->body());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.

Request unfortunately didn't work, but HTTP works great.
so just change the beginning of your code to $response = HTTP::withHeaders(...) and everything works like a dream :)

Comment: Could someone help me out here - Im trying to do something similar here but i keep getting a 404 response from jira

The docs state its due to lack of permissions or incorrect issue number but thats not correct as i can uploa/attach d a file with no issues using the lesstif/php-jira-rest-client package

Just wondering if any of you ran into the same problem?